# Swift: Default Storyboard background Image for all ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Is there a way to set (preferably in storyboard IB) an image, which, will serve as the background image for all ViewControllers in the whole storyboard. I don't want to have to add a background image in every ViewController or replicate that in code.

Comment: please see my updated answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would could create a `UIViewController` subclass (e.g. name it `DefaultViewController`) that sets a specific background color in one of the initialization methods (e.g. viewDidLoad, but don't forget if you override this in a subclass of this class to call it's super  method).

Then, let all your view controllers inherit from `DefaultViewController`

Example code:

```
class DefaultViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = = UIColor.redColor()
  }
}

class SomeViewController: DefaultViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // this call makes the background red, you can also not override this method and it will work too
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is going to result in all UIViews having a blue background, which likely isn't desirable.

Comment: @SandyChapman that's a good point, actually I hadn't understood exactly what he wanted, will edit it